# Connect to Access DB from .NET VB with no installation or runtime files

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am developing an application for .net VB and I want to use MS Access database to store the data.

Is there anyway to natively connect to access from VB .net? Without installing runtimes, libraries or needing any installations at all – just the .exe files.

I need to do this because I am going to deploy on a site that hates ms access and won't allow users to install anything, hence the only way to install application is to copy the exe and data files into a folder.

I could use a library or dll as I can copy that as well, but I can absolutely not install anything.

Code I am using is

```
    dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;" 'ACCDB
    MyConnection.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource & dbPathAndFilename
    MyConnection.Open()
    MySql = "SELECT * FROM tblTreeData order by Sort;"
    MyAdaptor = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(MySql, MyConnection)
    MyAdaptor.Fill(MyDataSet, "TreeData")
    MyAdaptor.Dispose()
    MyConnection.Close()
```

This works ok on development machine with libraries installed, but this creates a runtime error when I try on target machine that doesn't have all the MS runtimes installed.

Comment: You could use JSON instead. Unless they also hate JSON. Ask for a white list - things *they* don't hate - to be sure.

Comment: If MS Office is already there, the libraries you need are built-in. If MS Office is not there, you have to provide them.

Comment: Jimi - If I don't have to install it, its ok. If I have to install it, its hated and forbidden.

Comment: Joel - They have office installed, but it doesn't work, I suspect because they have disabled MS access because they hate it.

Comment: Json.Net requires just a .dll. If they have MS Office already installed, ACE driver is there. You probably have a different bitness. ACE is usually installed in the 32 bit flavor. If your app is built targeting 64bit or AnyCPU in a 64 bit machine, then try to build targeting x86. It should work.

Comment: As suggested in the answer, if you use an MDB file then you can use the built-in Jet database engine. If you're not actually using Access itself, an MDB file will generally be just as good as an ACCDB file. There is also the option of using SQLite, which is what Microsoft recommend for file-based databases. In that case, you can just deploy a DLL or two with your app and it will work as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use JET (as opposed to ACE), then you don’t have to install anything. Windows, since about windows 98 (second editon) does include the JET database engine by default. 
However, JET is limited to mdb format files. If you need to use the newer file format accDB, then you have to use the ACE provider which is not installed by default.

So, if you going to use say Word, or power-point, or outlook, then of course since the dawn of the computer industry, then you need the appropriate libraries installed on the target computer.

And if you using say .net 4.5, then of course that library will also have to be installed.

However, keep in mind that you don’t necessary have to install Full access, or even install the Access runtime.

You can install the ACE database engine separate. So for the last 20 years, JET is installed on windows. You can however install the ACE data engine independent of Access.

This can be found here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Keep in mind that both a x32 bit version, and x64 bit version of the ACE data engine is available.

It is 25 megs in size, so not small. However at least the data engine is far less trouble then having to install the free Access runtime, or (gasp) a full edition of Access. (last time I looked, they are in the 200 meg range size wise).

Keep in mind that you want to choose the correct bit size of the ACE engine to download + install.

In most cases I do recommend that you install the x32 bit version, but this would STRONG suggest then your force your .net project to x86 in place of “any cpu” for the .net project settings.

Comment: Thanks Albert, I will try using the inbuilt JET route, since I am only using the DB as a holder of data to be accessed by my .NET program, I don't need ACE engine.